# xpath поиск текста с пробелами

Tags: xpath

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему xpath `//div[@class='message__main' and contains(.,"1 620,9 ₽")]` не воспринимает внутри `contains()` пробелы? Что за проблема с пробелами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что это не обычный пробел, а неразрывный. В юникоде обозначается как `0xA0`, поэтому ваше выражение должно быть таким:

```
//div[@class="message__main" and contains(., "1\xA0620,9\xA0₽")]
```

Comment: только у меня не прям так вышло, а с `\u00A0 `